# How to launch app into background on iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, simulator

Events like location changes launch concerning app into background if it is not launched yet. But I don't see how to simulate such scenarios on simulator. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible with iOS Simulator found in ***current public*** SDK.

I know this is borderline breaking NDA, but you should take a look at Hardware menu item of new iOS Simulator that comes with Xcode 4.2 beta.